# Can I self host a Web UI with ServiceStack?

Tags: .net, servicestack

I'm evaluating ServiceStack (so far it rocks).
I have self hosting webservices working but I can't see how I can self host a UI, or even if this can be done.

*Self hosting is ideal for us, the UI will be occasionally used by a limited number of internal users to configure some back-end services*

I've looked at customising an AppHost `AppHostHttpListenerBase` but can't see where to get started.

Any help or direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ServiceStack's [RazorRockstars GitHub Project](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/) shows multiple configurations of the Razor Rockstars website in the different supported hosts:

- [ASP.NET Host](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/tree/master/src/RazorRockstars.WebHost) - live demo at [razor.servicestack.net](http://razor.servicestack.net)
- [Standalone Self Host](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/tree/master/src/RazorRockstars.SelfHost) - live demo at [razor-console.servicestack.net](http://razor-console.servicestack.net)
- [Standalone Windows Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/tree/master/src/RazorRockstars.WinService)

It sounds like you want to look at the Stand-Alone Self Host Console Application or Stand-Alone Windows Service which both include their own HttpListener.

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot, how did I not think to look for the sources of the sample projects? Thanks again mate.

Comment: And can I use servicestack to self host a large asp.net app (e.g. not razor) ?

Comment: @Jonesome ServiceStack Services can be hosted in the same App as a classic Web Forms App as it's just registered as a [raw ASP.NET IHttpAsyncHandler](http://docs.servicestack.net/architecture-overview). It doesn't host the WebForm pages themselves (ASP.NET's doing that) but it can enable [integration of existing WebForm Pages](http://docs.servicestack.net/servicestack-integration) by having them inherit `ServiceStackPage` giving them access to ServiceStack Services/deps. It also has an alternative to Razor http://templates.servicestack.net which can run anywhere, e.g classic MVC + All AppHosts

Comment: @mythz Thanks! Does that mean that a classic asp.net app can be made self hosting (e.g. in a windows service, outside IIS) by using servicestack, or does that mean I have to port templates to razor? (We have too many to port)

Comment: @Jonesome No WebForms requires ASP.NET, can’t be self hosted.